# How to handle no values in pandas from sql server

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

In my sql server query returns one line with one column having a null:

[image]

I import this query in a data frame using pd.read_sql:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver)
df = pd.read_sql(sql=sql, con=cnxn)
cnxn.close()
```

When I print, the Null becomes a None:

```
      nim  employees
0  None    24500.0
```

dtypes are:

```
nim           object
employees    float64
dtype: object
```

I would like to fill or replace the None with a value. 
When I do this:

```
   if (df.nim == 'None').bool():
        print(1)
    else:
        print(2)
```

it prints 2. When I do

```
 if df.nim is None:
        print(1)
    else: 
        print(2)
```

Still 2. I tried df.fillna(value=pd.np.nan, inplace=True) and .replace(None, np.nan) and it's not working.

How should I handle this change in from SQL to pandas DataFrame?

I want to apply this change on all columns if a null exists

Comment: try `df.nim.replace({'None': np.nan})`  ,which assumes that you have done `import numpy as np`

Comment: @steven you are correct, the dict is the way to go. Thanks